# Android Studio can't find javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor

Tags: android, android-annotations, java-annotations

I want to learn Annotation, and i create a demo project.
But when I create a class extends AbstractProcessor, Android Studio can't find this class. How can I add it.

Answer (score 18):

In Android Studio, if you go on `File > New > New Module` and select `Java Library` instead of `Android Library`, you should then be able to extend AbstractProcessor.

Comment: Very Good. Thank you.